# Crossfade between stacked elements

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fadein

So I have three stacked elements, i.e.

markup:

```
<div id="banner-1" class="banner-background"></div>
<div id="banner-2" class="banner-background"></div>
<div id="banner-3" class="banner-background"></div>

<a class="menu-link banner-1-link">1</a>
<a class="menu-link banner-2-link">2</a>
<a class="menu-link banner-3-link">3</a>
```

jquery:

for each link, i want to switch to the corresponding element and fade between. however this is causing weird problems, with the third element keep showing on fade. Is there also a better way to go about this so that is more dynamic, so say if I wanted to add 4 or 5 it would work too?

```
    $('.menu-link').on('mouseenter', function(){
        var menuLink = $(this);

        if (menuLink.hasClass('banner-1-link')){
            $('#banner-1').animate({'opacity': 0}, 100, function (){
                $('#banner-1').css('z-index', '3');
            }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 600);
                $('#banner-2').css('z-index', '0');
                $('#banner-3').css('z-index', '0');
        }

        else if (menuLink.hasClass('banner-2-link')){
            $('#banner-2').animate({'opacity': 0}, 100, function (){
                $('#banner-2').css('z-index', '3');
            }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 600);
                $('#banner-3').css('z-index', '0');
                $('#banner-1').css('z-index', '0');
        }

        else {
            $('#banner-3').animate({'opacity': 0}, 100, function (){
                $('#banner-3').css('z-index', '3');
            }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 600);
                $('#banner-2').css('z-index', '0');
                $('#banner-1').css('z-index', '0');
        }
});
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit:

CSS:

```
.banner-background{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#banner-1{
    z-index: 3;
}

#banner-2{
    z-index: 0;
}

#banner-3{
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Are the elements absolutely positioned to the same location?

Comment: Yep (: absoloutely positioned

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that adheres to your issue..

Comment: i think your issues are with the z-indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data` attr.

HTML

```
<div id="banner-1" class="banner-background"></div>
<div id="banner-2" class="banner-background"></div>
<div id="banner-3" class="banner-background"></div>

<a class="menu-link banner-1-link" data-banner="banner-1">1</a>
<a class="menu-link banner-2-link" data-banner="banner-2">2</a>
<a class="menu-link banner-3-link" data-banner="banner-3">3</a>
```

JS

```
$('.menu-link').on('mouseenter', function(){
    var $menuLink = $(this),
        $banner = $('#' + $menuLink.data('banner'));

    $banner.animate({'opacity': 1}, 100, function (){
        $(this).css('z-index', '3');
    });
    $('.banner-background').not($banner).css('z-index', '0');

});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rn686/)

Comment: I can see this works in the fiddle, but for some reason I'm still having an issue with the third image randomly flashing upbetween hovering over others...

Comment: $banner.animate({'opacity': 0}, 100, function (){
           $(this).css('z-index', '3');
       }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 600);
       $('.banner-background').not($banner).css('z-index', '0');

Any idea why this would make the third banner appear between every fade?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you need -- fade ALL the banners out, then change the z-index as needed before fading them all in again:

```
$('.menu-link').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var menuLink = $(this);
    $banners = $('#banner-1,#banner-2,#banner-3');

    $banners.stop().animate({'opacity':0},100, function() {
        $banners.css({'z-index':0});
        if (menuLink.hasClass('banner-1-link')) {
            $('#banner-1').css({'z-index':3});
        } else if (menuLink.hasClass('banner-2-link')) {
            $('#banner-2').css({'z-index':3});
        } else if (menuLink.hasClass('banner-3-link')) {
            $('#banner-3').css({'z-index':3});
        };
        $banners.animate({'opacity':1},600);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/GbbVU/

Comment: Thats more of a fade in and out than a cross fade though? I need them cross fade one over the other. the solution works above apart from a small glitch, not sure why but the third image keeps appearing between the fade

Answer (score 0):

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/k4EkG/1/

html

```
<div class="banner" id="banner-1"></div>
<div class="banner" id="banner-2"></div>
<div class="banner" id="banner-3"></div>
<a data-banner="1" class="menu-link">1</a>
<a data-banner="2" class="menu-link">2</a>
<a data-banner="3" class="menu-link">3</a>​
```

js

```
$('.menu-link').on('mouseenter', function(){
    var menuLink = $(this),
        banner = menuLink.data('banner');

    $('.banner').not(this).animate({'opacity': 0}, 100);
    $('#banner-' + banner).animate({'opacity': 1}, 600);

});​
```

css

```
.banner {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}
#banner-1 {
    background-color:blue;
}
#banner-2 {
    background-color:red;
    opacity:0;
}
#banner-3 {
    background-color:green;
    opacity:0;
}
```

using `data` is the way to go here in order for it to be dynamic.

Comment: Why the following line ? `$('.banner').not(this).animate({'opacity': 0}, 100);`

Comment: since im not using z-index, it will hide the other banners except the one that was mouseentered

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.menu-link').on('mouseenter', function(){


                      var $menuLink = $(this);
                      var $banner = $('#' + $menuLink.data('banner'));

                        $banner.css('opacity', 0);
                        $banner.parent().append($banner);

                        // fade in relevant banner
                        $banner.animate({'opacity': 0}, 100, function (){
                        }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 600);
    });
```

I needed to append the image instead. So we take each image, and append it to a parent container.

```
<div class="banner-back-container">
     <div class="banner-background" id="banner-1"></div>
      <div class="banner-background" id="banner-2"></div>
      <div class="banner-background" id="banner-3"></div>
 </div>

<li><a href="#" class="active menu-link" data-banner="banner-1">Latest collection</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="menu-link" data-banner="banner-2">Must have collection</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="menu-link" data-banner="banner-3">Coming soon</a></li>
```